# overloading >> operator for user defined string class

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

### Question

The problem is that i am trying to get user input using insertion operator and initialising the value `thechars`, to allocate the size to thechars i need the length of input, how do i get it?? And initialise in insertion operator.

Main problem is with insertion operator.

When i run the program it shows the segmentation fault,

plz help

```
class string1
{    
  private:
    int len;
    char *thechars;

    //friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&,string1&);##
    //friend istream& operator>>(istream&,string1&);##

  public:
    //string1() :len(0),thechars(NULL){}
    string1()
    {
      thechars = new char[1];
      thechars[0] = '\0';
      len=0;
      // cout << "\tDefault string constructor\n";
      // ConstructorCount++;
    }
};

// this is the insertion operator i use
istream& operator>>(istream& in, string1& tpr)
{
  in >> tpr.thechars;
  //tpr.thechars[i+1]='\0';
  return in;
}

//this one is the extraction operator
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,string1& prt)
{
  for(int i=0;i<prt.len;i++)
    out<<prt.thechars[i];

  return out;
}

// main function##
string1 str;
cout << "enter first string" << endl;
cin >> str;
cout << str << endl;
```

Comment: How are you doing memory allocation for the **thechars** in your insertion operator ??

Comment: @DumbCoder I think the question is exactly about this.

Answer (score 2):

If `in` is a file input stream, you can do the following:

```
in.seekg(0, ios::end);
length = in.tellg();
in.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```

The other option is reading the input stream char by char and double the size of `thechars` each time it's exhausted. First, introduce one more variable to store the currently allocated size of the buffer --- `allocSize`. After that update the constructor and `operator<<` as follows.

Constructor:

```
string1()
{
    allocSize = 1; // initially allocated size
    thechars = new char[allocSize];
    thechars[0] = '\0';
    len=0;
}
```

Input operator:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, string1& tpr)
{
    char inp;
    while (in.get(inp)) {
        // end-of-input delimiter (change according to your needs)
        if (inp == ' ')
            break;
        // if buffer is exhausted, reallocate it twice as large
        if (tpr.len == tpr.allocSize - 1) {
            tpr.allocSize *= 2;
            char *newchars = new char[tpr.allocSize];
            strcpy(newchars, tpr.thechars);
            delete[] tpr.thechars;
            tpr.thechars = newchars;
        }
        // store input char
        tpr.thechars[tpr.len++] = inp;
        tpr.thechars[tpr.len] = '\0';
    }
}
```

But the best option is to use `std::string` as a type for `thechars`. Do you really need all this manual memory handling?

Comment: actually i was trying to build my string library ,for that i need to overload insertion opertator ,can you elaborate the second option in which you tell about reading it char by char..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of giving the `in` a `char*` give it a regular string. Then you can extract the data yourself.

```
istream& operator>>(istream& in, string1& tpr)
{
  string temp;
  in >> temp;
  tpr.len = temp.length + 1;
  tpr.thechars = new char[tpr.len];
  tpr.thechars[temp.length] = '\0';
  strcpy(tpr.thechars, &temp[0], tpr.len);
  return in;
}
```

Comment: still in strcpy(tpr.thechars,&temp[0]),without tpr.len it will work.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote

```
 in>> tpr.thechars; // where thechars="\0";
```

You allocated only one byte, but i guess you are input string with more bytes.
I think error here.